# Is there a way to override base settings in a yaml file using node.js?

Tags: node.js, ant, yaml

I remember using build.properties files in ANT and having the ability to override properties defined in build.xml, that were base properties (defaults / convention over configuration).

Is it possible to do this with a base yaml file and then override what needs to change in another yaml file that overrides it, using some library from node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good **hierarchical configuration** libraries that supports YAML, such as:

- https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config
- https://github.com/indexzero/nconf